Sort array with click
I want to sort my new array "posts2" when I click the buttons. But nothings happens when I click the buttons. The sort buttons work if I change "post2" to the original array "posts" in the methods function "sort3". But how should I change my code to be able to sort only the new array "post2"? I guess I have tried to call "posts2" in the wrong way because it's in a computed property.

<button @click="sort3('id')">Sort the posts by id</button>
  <button @click="sort3('field')">Sort the posts by field</button>
  <button @click="sort3('author')">Sort the posts by author</button>
  <p v-for="item in newPosts" :key="item.id">{{ item.id + " " + item.type + " " + item.titles + " <b> " + item.meta['string_binding'] + " </b> " + item.author }}</p>


export default {
    data() { 
      return {
        posts: [],
        posts2: [],
      };
    },
    mounted() {
        fetch('http://localhost/Wordpress/wp-json/wp/v2/posts')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => this.posts = data)
        .then(err => console.log(err)) 
    },
    methods: {
        sort3(msg){
            if (msg == 'field') {
                this.posts2 = this.posts2.sort((a, b) => a.meta['string_binding'] - b.meta['string_binding']);
            } else if (msg == 'id') {
                this.posts2 = this.posts2.sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id);
            } else if (msg == 'author') {
              this.posts2 = this.posts2.sort((a, b) => a.author - b.author);
          } 
        }
},
    computed: {
      newPosts() {
        const titleMap = {
        post: 'SinglePost',
        page: 'SinglePage',
        movies: 'SingleMovie'
      };
        const posts2 = this.posts.map(item => ({...item, titles: titleMap[item.type]})).slice(0, 5);
        return posts2;
  }
},
}

EDIT:
OK I changed my code. Added
.then(data => this.posts2 = this.posts.map(item => ({...item})).slice(0, 5))
and changed the computed property to:
     newPosts() {
       const titleMap = {
       post: 'SinglePost',
       page: 'SinglePage',
       movies: 'SingleMovie'
     };
  return this.posts2.map(item => ({...item, titles: titleMap[item.type]}));
 }
},

Everything works but is it a good and correct solution?

the computed property is returning the mapped value of this.posts.  assigning it to const posts2 does nothing other than rename it as a new local variable.  if you want to sort the component variable posts2, you would use it like you do in your sort3 function, using the this keyword.  In your computed, you could do return this.posts2.map(...)

Thanks but nothing works when I change the code to that. Could you please change the code to make it work?
    newPosts() {
        const titleMap = {
        post: 'SinglePost',
        page: 'SinglePage',
        movies: 'SingleMovie'
      };
        return this.posts2.map(item => ({...item, titles: titleMap[item.type]})).slice(0, 5);
  }
},


try walking through what your code is doing.  now your computed is returning the mapped this.posts2 like you wanted, but this.posts2 is initially an empty array and you're not giving it any other value anywhere else.  probably when you fetch you want to assign both this.posts and this.posts2 with the fetched data

Shouldn't my computed be like before but with return "this.posts"?
     newPosts() {
       const titleMap = {
       post: 'SinglePost',
       page: 'SinglePage',
       movies: 'SingleMovie'
     };
const posts2 = this.posts.map(item => ({...item, titles: titleMap[item.type]})).slice(0, 5);
       return this.posts2;
 }
},


Sure I can assign both this.posts and this.posts2 with the fetched data, like so:
.then(data => this.posts2 = this.posts.slice(0, 5))  but I thought posts2 was already a copy of posts in my computed property.

a computed property only reevaluates when any of it's dependencies changes.  if the computed only uses this.post, and you're not updating this.post, then the computed doesn't update.  since you're sorting this.posts2, the computed should use this.posts2, that way the sort causes the computed to rerun itself.
